# Retrieving data from AJAX requests using Scrapy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

So I have a product page where I see several different products that are being generated only when I click on the product.  I see the dynamic content being loaded in the XHR tab in Network Console with a single GET Request for every item I click on.

Is there a way to select every product on that page and scrape specific data just like normal? I've tried scraping websites that don't use AJAX with ease but I'm pretty stumped here. I was going to scrape the products in order but when I went to the headers and looked at the request URL, I noticed that the item code for each product is not in order. For example the first item on the page has a product code of 46837 and then the one right below it has a product code of 68392. Or should I just be using selenium or splash to capture these AJAX calls?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give the URL so we can play with it? In general, if you are able to  infer the pattern of AJAX call (from information from product list), it's doable.

Comment: For sure with Selenium or some other tool that processes the AJAX interaction you should be fine. Using Selenium will delay the scraping process, but it really depends on your needs. You can have an example of it here: http://www.6020peaks.com/2014/12/how-to-scrape-hidden-web-data-with-python/